# What is the best way to clear an entire structure in Structured text

Tags: plc, st, structured-text, iec61131-3

This is how I have it now

```
TYPE MyType: STRUCT
    name: STRING[20];
    input: INT;
    output: INT;
    END_STRUCT
END_TYPE
```

```
PROGRAM PLC_PRG:
    VAR
        struct:  MyType;
        struct_NULL:  MyType;
        error: BOOL;
    END_VAR

    IF error THEN
        struct := struct_NULL;
    END_IF
END_PROGRAM
```

Is there another way to null the structure, without declearing and using `struct_NULL`

Comment: I would go this way too. Looks good to me.

Answer (score 7):

Just use `SysMemSet` (Codesys library SysMem), `MemSet` (Codesys library MemoryUtils) or `MEMSET` (TwinCAT 3 library Tc2_System) function to set all data to 0.

```
SysMemSet(
    pDest       := ADR(TestStruct), 
    udiValue    := 0, 
    udiCount    := SIZEOF(TestStruct)
);
```

You can write a simple helper function for it :)

```
FUNCTION F_Clear : BOOL
VAR_INPUT
    Target : ANY;
END_VAR
VAR
END_VAR


SysMemSet(
    pDest       := Target.pValue, 
    udiValue    := 0, 
    udiCount    := Target.diSize
);
```

Usage, works for all kinds of variables!

```
F_Clear(TestStruct);
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this would work, but can you guarantee that no one will write in the code something like this:

```
struct_NULL.input := 7;
```

So I would prefer to write an short function which set back all value to default:

```
FUNCTION F_setToDefault_MyStruct : MyStruct
VAR
    DefaultStruct   : MyStruct;
END_VAR

F_setToDefault_MyStruct := DefaultStruct;
```

So in the programm you can call:

```
//set struct to default values
TestStruct:=F_setToDefault_MyStruct();
```

I know, a lot more code, but no one can change the initial values in struct_NULL, and I think it´s much more easier to read and understand

Answer (score 0):

A simple way would be to keep the empty default structure that could clear another structure of the same type by assignment:

```
  MyStructure_new: MyStructureType;
  MyStructure: MyStructureType;
  MyStructure := MyStructureNew;
```

Differently from setting the memory directly, this approach would respect default values other than 0 or `false` in the structure fields. `MyStructure_new` can be defined as a private variable of the function.